# How can I create a link to permission group and configuration page on module install page?

Tags: 8

When you install modules I can see some modules have links on the install page directly to the permission groups and the configuration page. How can I create those links for my own module?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For settings page, in `your_module.info.yml`

```
configure: 'your_module.route_to_settings.form'
```

Permissions link is automatically shown whenever you have permissions defined in your module.